# ¿Por qué en JavaScript un string es evaluado como true en una condicional?

Tags: javascript

No entiendo bien cómo evalúa la condición if el siguiente código, ya que da true y no sé por qué:

```
musica = "Rock";
if(musica) {

/*codigo*/

} // que estaría evaluando ahí? Porque da true?
```

En otros lenguajes (como Java) te diría que un String no se puede convertir en booleano, entonces en JavaScript, ¿qué sucede y por qué da true?

Comment: Javascript entiende TRUE cualquier valor que no sea FALSE, 0, "0", NULL, undefined (y puede que me deje alguno)

Comment: Es la caja de Pandora de Javascript y con el que cualquier desarollador en este lenguaje se atasca alguna vez. Se llama *type coercion* y es una efecto inmediato de tener un lenguaje dinámico (no tipado). El *parser* intenta por todos los medios interpretar la intención del código. Te dejo un [link](https://medium.com/developers-arena/type-coercion-in-javascript-c973b369b272) explicativo. Ninguna de las respuestas aquí lo explica como es debido.

Answer (score 10):

Como mencionó Arnau en su comentario:

> Javascript entiende TRUE cualquier valor que no sea FALSE, 0, "0", NULL, undefined

Sucede que el valor (en este caso de la variable `musica`) está siendo "casteado", o convertido implícitamente, a Boolean. Cualquier string no vacío es evaluado como true.

La lectura recomendada en este caso es [coerción de tipos (type coercion)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion):

> La coerción de tipo es la conversión automática o implícita de los valores de un tipo de datos a otro (como de strings a números). La conversión de tipos es similar a la coerción de tipos porque ambos convierten valores de un tipo de datos a otro con una diferencia clave: la coerción de tipos es **implícita** mientras que la conversión de tipos **puede ser implícita o explícita**.

Adaptando la [respuesta de John Kugelman en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923684/12788110):

En base a lo escrito en la [Especificación del Lenguaje ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) (ES2020 al momento de consultarlo):

> ### 13.6 La sentencia `if`
>
> #### 13.6.7 Semántica en Tiempo de Ejecución: Evaluación
>
> *SentenciaIf*: **if** ( *Expresión* ) *Sentencia* **else** *Sentencia* se evalúa como sigue:
>
> 1. Asumamos que *exprRef* es el resultado de la evaluación de *Expresión*.
> 2. Si ToBoolean(*exprRef*) es **true**, entonces retorna el resultado de la evaluación de la primera *Sentencia*.
> 3. Sino, retorna el resultado de la evaluación de la segunda *Sentencia*.

---

> ### 7.1.2 ToBoolean(*argumento*)
>
> La operación abstracta **ToBoolean** convierte *argumento* en un valor de tipo Boolean de acuerdo a la siguiente tabla:
>
> #### Tabla - Conversiones ToBoolean
>
> | Tipo de Dato | Valor luego de conversión |
> | --- | --- |
> | Undefined | **false** |
> | Null | **false** |
> | Boolean | El resultado es igual al argumento de entrada (no hay conversión). |
> | Number | El resultado es **false** si el argumento es **+0**, **-0**, o **NaN**; caso contrario el resultado es **true**. |
> | String | El resultado es **false** si *argumento* es un String vacío (su longitud es cero); caso contrario el resultado es **true**. (<== este es el caso en la pregunta) |
> | Symbol | **true** |
> | BigInt | Si *argumento* es **0n**, el resultado es **false**; caso contario es **true**. |
> | Object | **true** |

---

Aplicándolo a tu caso:

```js
musica = "Rock";

/*
La regla dice que, si a través de la coerción con ToBoolean, la evaluación es true,
 entonces el resultado es true:
*/

if (musica){ //que es lo mismo que if(musica == true); aquí convertido implícitamente
  console.log('Fue evaluado como true en el primer if');
}
else{
  console.log('Fue evaluado como false en el primer if');
}
if(Boolean(musica)){ //convertido explícitamente con la función Boolean
  console.log('Fue evaluado como true en el segundo if');
}
else{
  console.log('Fue evaluado como false en el segundo if');
}

/*Ahora, ¿qué pasa si "musica" tiene una longitud de cero?*/

musica = '';

if (musica){
  console.log('Fue evaluado como true en el tercer if');
}
else{
  console.log('Fue evaluado como false en el tercer if');
}
if(Boolean(musica)){
  console.log('Fue evaluado como true en el cuarto if');
}
else{
  console.log('Fue evaluado como false en el cuarto if');
}


//(P.D.: Podría acortar los *if* en una línea, pero la idea es que quienes recién inician en la programación con JS también comprendan la idea)
```

Answer (score 5):

Lo que estas evaluando es si tu variable tiene un valor. Puedes comprobarlo de la siguiente manera, verás que la variable que no tiene asignado un valor no pasa por la condicional, considerando que tu variable es una cadena o string.

```js
var musica1;
var musica2 = "Rock";

if(musica1) {
 console.log("musica1");
}
if(musica2) {
 console.log("musica2");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

En varios lenguajes de tipado (Java,C,etc), este error se presentaría, debido a que no se pueden cambiar los tipos de dato, sin embargo, en Javascript, no sucede esto

JavaScript interpreta como `false` todos los valores que sean:

- "0"
- 0
- false
- undefined
- null
- ""

Todos los otros valores los interpreta como `true`, en realidad, estás comprobando si tu variable no es ninguno de los valores anteriormente mencionados

```js
console.log("" == false)
console.log("0" == false)
console.log(0 == false)
```

Además, JavaScript, interpreta `false` como `0` y `true` como `1`

```js
console.log(false == 0)
console.log(true == 1)
```

Para obtener tipos de elementos usa `typeof`

```js
console.log(typeof null)
console.log(typeof undefined)
console.log(typeof function(){})
console.log(typeof {})
console.log(typeof [])
console.log(typeof "hola mundo")
console.log(typeof true)
console.log(typeof 1)
```

Comment: No está comprobando si existe o no existe... Y "*para comprobar su tipo usa `tyepof`*" se queda como una afirmación bastante descontextualizada. Falta mucho desarrollo en la respuesta o quizás no tienes tan claro qué significa la *type coercion*.

Answer (score 3):

La respuesta es que `JAVA` es un lenguaje `tipado` donde

```
if(param){} //param debe ser booleado, u otro tipo de dato segun su uso
```

y no solo ocurre en `JAVA`, tambien en `C#`, `C++` y todo lenguaje `tipado`, ya que estos evaluan el `tipo de dato` antes de procesarlo.

mientras que en `Javascrip` se evalua si es `null, false, undefined`, y cualquier valor diferente te dará `true`, los lenguajes `no tipados` evaluan primero `si ha sido declarado, o tiene algun valor` antes de procesarlo.